# Пин пользователя всё время с верху Yandex MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

В коде выставляю значение zIndex для pin, accuracyCircle очень маленьким (например 0), а для остальных пинов большим. На 3.0 всё нормально работало, а на 3.1 перестало.

swift 4.2, xcode 10

Answer (score 2):

В **MapKit 3.1** появилась возможность менять порядок отрисовки слоев (а вернее, их частей, выделенных по типу объектов). Также, стало возможным создавать свои собственные слои *map* *object*'ов. *User location* получил свой слой, поэтому он рисуется по умолчанию всегда выше *placemark*'ов из *YMKMap.mapObjects*. Это можно изменить при помощи следующего кода:

```
let sublayers = map.sublayerManager
let userLocationIndex = sublayers.findFirstOf(
    withLayerId: YMKLayerNames.userLocationLayerName(), featureType: YMKSublayerFeatureType.placemarks)!
let mapObjectsIndex = sublayers.findFirstOf(
    withLayerId: YMKLayerNames.mapObjectsLayerName(), featureType: YMKSublayerFeatureType.placemarks)!
sublayers.moveBeforeWith(from: userLocationIndex.uintValue, to: mapObjectsIndex.uintValue)
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло для андроид)